# Tiling matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, syntax, matrix, tiling

Here's an interesting question :)

I have two "vectors of matrices" which I want to tile like the hankel function does for regular vertices.
For example:
Column Vector:

```
10
00

20
00

30
00
```

Row vector:

```
30 40 50 60
00 00 00 00
```

The resulting matrix needs to be:

```
10 20 30 40
00 00 00 00

20 30 40 50
00 00 00 00

30 40 50 60
00 00 00 00
```

Note that the 0 values can be changed, the resulting structure is the important part.

A related question:
I looked in the command "edit repmat" and saw some interesting syntax I couldn't find help for:

```
A=[1,3;2,4];
X=[1,1;2,2];
B=A(X,X);
```

and B ends up being

```
1 3 1 3
2 4 2 4
1 3 1 3
2 4 2 4
```

which is basically repmat(A,2,2);

So my question is, what is this syntax: A(X,X)?

Thanks a lot!

Ofer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to tile a set of *matrices* the way [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) tiles *values*, here's one way you can do it. First, you can put all of your unique matrices in one cell array:

```
mat = [1 0; 0 0];
cArray = {mat 2.*mat 3.*mat 4.*mat 5.*mat 6.*mat};  %# Your 6 unique matrices
```

Now, if you want the first 3 matrices running down the first column and the last 4 matrices running across the last row, you can create an index matrix using [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html):

```
>> index = hankel(1:3,3:6);

index =

     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
```

Then index your cell array with `index` and use [CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert the resulting cell array to one matrix:

```
>> cell2mat(cArray(index))

ans =

     1     0     2     0     3     0     4     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     2     0     3     0     4     0     5     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     0     4     0     5     0     6     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

For the second part of your question, when you perform an indexing operation like `A(X,Y)`, you are using the elements of `X` as row indices and the elements of `Y` as column indices into `A`. *Every combination* of values in `X` and `Y` is used. So, if `X = [x1 x2 x3 x4]` and `Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4]`, then the result of `B = A(X,Y)` is equivalent to:

```
B = [A(x1,y1) A(x1,y2) A(x1,y3) A(x1,y4); ...
     A(x2,y1) A(x2,y2) A(x2,y3) A(x2,y4); ...
     A(x3,y1) A(x3,y2) A(x3,y3) A(x3,y4); ...
     A(x4,y1) A(x4,y2) A(x4,y3) A(x4,y4)];
```

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for answering. Maybe I wasn't clear because it's not exactly what I meant.
For the first part, I don't want to interleave things. I want the hankel structure but for matrices instead of individual scalars.
That is, instead of where hankel would put a number, I want a whole matrix in that position.

As for the second part, I guess my question was even more basic - what does A(X,X) do? Actually, what does A(X,Y) do to be more general?

Again thank you very much for answering :)

Comment: Wow! Totally awesome! It's exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)